# Golang Left/Right shift behaviour for signed numbers

Tags: go, int, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, signed

Can someone please explain the left/right shift behaviour in Golang. Please refer the sample code here: https://play.golang.org/p/7vjwCbOEkw

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var lf int8 = -3
    fmt.Printf("-3 : %08b\n", lf)
    fmt.Printf("<<1: %08b\n", lf<<1)
    fmt.Printf("<<2: %08b\n", lf<<2)
    fmt.Printf("<<3: %08b\n", lf<<3)
    fmt.Printf("<<4: %08b\n", lf<<4)
    fmt.Printf("<<5: %08b, %d\n", lf<<5, lf<<5)
    fmt.Printf("<<6: %08b, %d\n", lf<<6, lf<<6)
    fmt.Printf("<<7: %08b, %d\n", lf<<7, lf<<7)
    fmt.Printf("<<8: %08b, %d\n", lf<<8, lf<<8)
    fmt.Printf("<<9: %08b, %d\n", lf<<9, lf<<9)
}

-3 : -0000011
<<1: -0000110
<<2: -0001100
<<3: -0011000
<<4: -0110000
<<5: -1100000, -96
<<6: 01000000, 64
<<7: -10000000, -128
<<8: 00000000, 0
<<9: 00000000, 0
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean, what is the output and what do you expect to see? Your link does not work.

Comment: @gonutz: https://play.golang.org/p/7vjwCbOEkw

Comment: See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators and look for shift. There is not much to explain.

Comment: @Volker Thank you

Answer (score 5):

`-3` is, in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), `11111101` and what you see when the program prints `-0000011` is a `-` and the binary representation of the absolute value of the number. In two's complement, the highest bit is `0` for positive (including zero), and `1` for negative numbers. If you shift this number (`11111101`) left, the lower 7 bits move one to the left and a `0` comes in from the right, replacing the lowest bit. Shifting as you do in your example will result in:

```
11111101  -3
11111010  -6
11110100  -12
11101000  -24
11010000  -48
10100000  -96
01000000  64
10000000  -128
00000000  0
00000000  0
...
```

You just have to consider all the bit patterns as two's complement, once you know how that works, everything will make sense.